# I am trying to create a computer that uses the robot class to play freeze tag

Tags: javascript, java, boolean

```
while(computerIsFrozen==false)
{
  while(computerIsTagger==true)
  {
    if(nextToARobot)
    {
      playerIsFrozen = true;
      computerIsTagger = false;

    }
  }   

  if(computerIsFrozen==true)
  {
    for(int k=1; k<=8; k++)
     {
       turnLeft();
     }
     computerIsTagger = true;
     computerIsFrozen = false;
   }
}
​
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Computer.java:15: error: illegal start of type
   while(computerIsFrozen==false)
   ^
Computer.java:15: error: <identifier> expected
   while(computerIsFrozen==false)
```

why am I getting the error `illegal start of type on the first line` and also `identifier expected on the first line`. There also might be some more errors that I am not sure of. `computerIsFrozen` is initialized to false and so is `computerIsTagger`.

Comment: javascript or java, they're 2 unrelated language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
   while(computerIsFrozen==false)
   {
      while(computerIsTagger==true)
      {
         if(nextToARobot)
         {
         playerIsFrozen = true;
         computerIsTagger = false;
      
      }
   }  // <-- remove this curly brace
   
   
   if(computerIsFrozen==true)
   {
      for(int k=1; k<=8; k++)
      {
      turnLeft();
      }
   computerIsTagger = true;
   computerIsFrozen = false;
   }
} 
​
```

Comment: +1 actually your answer may be the correct one - it is hard to tell with the amount of incorrect indentation

Comment: Hi Scary Wombat, Thanks. btw, there are many possible ways in that code snippet that could have been corrected. Option 1 is my answer above, Option 2 is removing the curly brace in the end that will occur the last if statement will be outside the while statement.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing curly

```
   if(nextToARobot)
   {
     playerIsFrozen = true;
     computerIsTagger = false;
   } // here
```

Comment: I am still getting the identifier expected and the illegal start of type error.

Comment: Computer.java:15: error: illegal start of type
   while(computerIsFrozen==false)
   ^
Computer.java:15: error: <identifier> expected
   while(computerIsFrozen==false)